# How can access to WebAppUser in Telegram web app

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I created a Web App with `Telegram` and `ReactJS`, after that I enabled web app debug mod to see inspect options.

The only way I can get user information is:

```js
var search = Telegram.WebApp.initData
var converted = JSON.parse('{"' + search.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}', function(key, value) { return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) })
JSON.parse(converted.user)
```

Based on: https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#webappinitdata

But all the options the document calls are not there and there is another API which I need it is [WebAppUser document](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#webappuser), and again I can not access it.

**My question is how can I be able to access it?**

I see this JS file that `Telegram` says to add in our HTML, but I could not find the `WebAppUser` into it.

```html
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
```

Short Video and demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKFZd2rWk24

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that [WebAppUser section](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#webappuser) describes the properties of a `user` encoded in `window.Telegram.WebApp.initData`. So it should be safe to use validated and decoded information stored in `window.Telegram.WebApp.initData` to obtain a user data.

NB! It's my guess tho. I faced the same question in fact.